# Directory expansion does not work in standalone deployment mode : Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to deploy a spark streaming consuming Kafka topic job on a standalone spark cluster using the following command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class MaxwellCdc.MaxwellSreaming
~/cdc/cdc_2.11-0.1.jar --jars ~/cdc/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar,
~/cdc/kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar,~/cdc/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar,
~/cdc/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.1.jar
```

and getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringDeserializer
at MaxwellCdc.MaxwellSreaming$.main(MaxwellSreaming.scala:30)
at MaxwellCdc.MaxwellSreaming.main(MaxwellSreaming.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the documentation:

> When using spark-submit, the application jar along with any jars
>   included with the --jars option will be automatically transferred to
>   the cluster. URLs supplied after --jars must be separated by commas.
>   That list is included in the driver and executor classpaths.
>   **Directory expansion does not work with --jars.**.

**What is directory expansion?**

Expanding a file name means converting a relative file name to an absolute one. Since this is done relative to a default directory, you must specify the default directory name as well as the file name to be expanded. **It also involves expanding abbreviations like ~/**.

Therefore, try providing the absolute path for all the jars that are being provided with `--jars` option. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, dude, it works. Another problem arises when I try to submit my spark sql batch using the command ./spark-submit --jars /root/batch/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar --class BatchProcessor /root/batch/mysqltocassandrabatch_2.11-0.1.jar. the exception is Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)

Comment: This seems to be more of the JDBC driver JAR you are using in your program. Try providing appropriate JAR to solve this.